# How do I create an Outlook "internet calendar subscription"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar, outlook-2007

For a new intranet application, I would like to let the user [add a calendar to their Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-subscribe-to-internet-calendars-HA010167325.aspx#BM2) so it can be easily looked at. The calendar would be read-only. How do I go about creating this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create an [iCal feed](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) which most clients can subscribe to. Use a `FileStreamResult` in your controller to post it down to clients. Get familiar with the ICS specification, it starts like this

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//{Calender of something}//NONSGML v1.0//EN
VERSION:1.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:{Name}
X-ORIGINAL-URL:{The Url obviously}
X-WR-CALDESC:{Calendar of Events For a new intranet application}
```

and ends with `END:VCALENDAR`. And here are events

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20101113
DTEND:20101115
DTSTAMP:20101110T154940
CREATED:20101109T201237
LAST-MODIFIED:20101109T201237
UID:{unique id}
SUMMARY:Nanaimo Artwalk 2010 (Free)
DESCRIPTION:{Description}
LOCATION:{Location}
URL:{url}
END:VEVENT
```

Now I don't know the ICS format really well so you should get more acquainted with it. Alternatively you can use [an open-source library](http://icalendar.codeplex.com/). When you create your feed write it as a file result.

```
private static FileResult iCalResult(string ics)
{
    return new FileStreamResult(WriteCal(ics), "text/calendar");
}

private static Stream WriteCal(string ics)
{
    var content = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ics);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(content);
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know if there was an "outlook way" or it iCal should be generated. I'll generate the iCal then.

Comment: there is an outlook way to do this trough exchange web services managed api's but this is easier and more more client agnostic..